# Add form values to Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

How is it possible to get values from a Html form to an Ajax.ActionLink method like the example below. Instead of "id=Model.DinnerID" I need to get the values of two textboxes that is in a Html form block?

Answer (score 0):

set id with id of the textbox(something like this: {id="textboxId"})